# Matching the first occurance of a number

Tags: regex

In regex how would you match the number in the following string:

```
first_occurrence_85
```

Would:
`([0-9][0-9])` do?

Edit: I meant to say any number of digits, so if its `first_occurrence_8438`, it should match 8438.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\d+` is enough.. `\d` matches with any digit..

Answer (score 0):

How about this: `^.*[0-9]+.*$"`
Will match any number of any character and after that atleast one numeric and then any number of any characters.